# Delphi ARC compilers memory management

Tags: delphi

I have read about ARC and I see that it is supported not by every compiler. So I guess that Delphi has not the same way to manage the memory in every scenario, correct? It depends from the compiler.

I have googled this but I find hard to understand the differences in the memory management between "classic" Delphi and ARC delphi. From what I've understood it calls `Free` automatically, so what is the difference in the code?

Please give me a code exmple if possible.

Comment: You want to know if you have to use Free or not?

Comment: Also that because I see that I cannot use it and I have to trick something with nil... but the try-finally block dissappears correct?

Comment: Why downvote to this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react

Comment: There are many articles on the topic of ARC. Certainly a great many with far better content than the answer you accepted here. Websearch would be more useful to you.

Comment: Ok good but at least I got an answer with simple code and simple words. I have understood so it's acceptable indeed.

Comment: If omits so much though. Still if you are content that's fine. Too bad for the future readers of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you look at the documentation, if you haven't already:

[Automatic Reference Counting in Delphi Mobile Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers).

Here you can find a complete explaination about this topic.

---

**Automatic Reference Counting**

Memory management in Delphi is not always the same because if you are using an ARC-enabled compiler, things are going to change.

To make it short, ARC is a way to manage an object's lifetime without the need to worry about object that you don't need.

This is how you normally use the objects (**non** ARC)

```
var
 a: TMyNiceClass;
begin

 a := TMyNiceClass.Create; 
 try
  a.somethingToDo();
 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

end;
```

Here I need to put the code inside a `try-finally` block, so I'm sure that my object will go away when I don't need it anymore (and I avoid memory leaks). Instead **under** ARC:

```
var
a: TMyNiceClass;
begin

 a := TMyNiceClass.Create;
 a.somethingToDo(); 

end;
```

The code above works fine, under ARC, because you don't need to `Free` and neither use the `try-finally` since it is "automatic". Also note that the destructor is called when you reach the *end;* statement, but if you want to stop using the object before the end you can use `a := nil`.

**Note**

In the traditional style calling `Free` invokes the destructor (unless the reference to the object was nil), in ARC style the `Free` assigns the reference to the object = nil.

Comment: Ok good. But memory leaks are the ones on the heap? What about a freeandnil?

Comment: Memory leaks happen when you call a lot of object but you don't free them. FreeAndNil frees the object and then sets its reference to nil.

Comment: And what is better bewteen free and freeandnil?

Comment: I don't think that there is the best, it depends from the situation. But I guess that we are going too far now, so give a look about it on embarcadero doc or ask a question if needed.

Comment: @user2590987 There are already a number of questions on this site discussing the nuances of both [Free](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+free) and [FreeAndNil](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+freeandnil). Look to those to improve your understanding.

Comment: I don't get this: " in ARC style the Free assigns the reference to the object = nil". This is wrong and confusing. I suppose you meant "in ARC, assigning a reference to object = nil may Free the instance, if no other reference of it still exists".

Answer (score 0):

ARC may be confusing, as implemented in Delphi compiler.
It is an unneeded compatibility breaker.

You may need a book to make it right: [Delphi Memory Management For Classic And ARC Compilers](http://sites.fastspring.com/epixeditions/product/delphimm).

Extract from the 4th of cover:

> Delphi provides a variety of types with their own memory management
>   logic, as well as two sets of compilers that provide different memory
>   management systems for classes.
>
> - Classic Delphi compiler currently supported on Windows and OSX platforms - using manual memory management while providing ARC for
>     certain types.
> - Next generation ARC Delphi compiler supported on mobile Android and iOS platforms, as well as Linux - using full ARC - Automatic Reference
>     Counting memory management system.
>
> Each memory management system has its good and bad sides. Each offers
>   solutions to some problems, but creates a whole range of other
>   problems. And each requires slightly different coding patterns and
>   practices. Knowing the strengths and weaknesses and understanding how
>   memory management system(s) work goes hand-in-hand with writing clean,
>   bug-free and maintainable code.

Comment: Thanks for your personal opinion and the copy/paste

Comment: It is a fact that if you need a book to understand it, and if you asked this very question above, that ARC is confusing. The copy & paste is identified as such, and is a very good sum-up of the whole point.